# Get the percentage of empty cells in a column for a certain group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Emma", "Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Emma", "Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Emma"), data = c(1, "", 3, 1, "",3, 4, "", 1, "", 1, 3, 3, 1, 3)
                 )
```

I would like to percentage of the empty cells for each person and create another dataframe. The results should looks like this:

```
df_result<-data.frame(name=c("Ben", "Bill", "Emma", "Jon", "Maria"), percentage=c(0, 0.33, 0.66, 0, 0.33))
```

I have tried the group_by function from dpylr package.

```
df_result<-df%>%group_by(name)%>%summarise(miss_count=count(data))
df_result$percentage<-1-(df_result$miss_count/3)
```

I have searched the answer for a long time. If it is duplicated, I am sincerely sorry.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mean` on a logical vector to get the percentage (`* 100`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(name) %>%
   summarise(miss_count = mean(data == ''))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  name  miss_count
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 Ben        0    
2 Bill       0.333
3 Emma       0.667
4 Jon        0    
5 Maria      0.333
```

Comment: Hello akrun, This is a great help! Thank you. Do you mind I ask why count() does not work in this case?

Comment: @Catherine `count` expects a data.frame/tibble as input whereas in your code, you are using `count(data)` whhere data is a vector/column

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can use `aggregate` as -

```
aggregate(data~name, df, function(x) sum(x == '')/length(x))

#   name      data
#1   Ben 0.0000000
#2  Bill 0.3333333
#3  Emma 0.6666667
#4   Jon 0.0000000
#5 Maria 0.3333333
```